# same regex but different results in Pandas vs. R

Tags: python, r, regex, pandas, stringr

Consider this simple regex aimed at extracting headlines

`(\w[\w-]+){2,}`

Running it in Python (`Pandas`) vs. R (`stringr`) gives totally different results!

In `stringr` the extraction works correctly: see how the `'this-is-a-very-nice-test'` is parsed correctly

```
library(stringr)
> str_extract_all('stackoverflow.stack.com/read/this-is-a-very-nice-test', 
+                 regex('(\\w[-\\w]+){2,}'))
[[1]]
[1] "stackoverflow"            "stack"                    "read"                     "this-is-a-very-nice-test"
```

In Pandas, well, the output is a bit puzzling

```
myseries = pd.Series({'text' : 'stackoverflow.stack.com/read/this-is-a-very-nice-test'})

myseries.str.extractall(r'(\w[-\w]+){2,}')
Out[51]: 
             0
     match    
text 0      ow
     1      ck
     2      ad
     3      st
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you also expecting the "com"?

Comment: May be `myseries.str.extractall(r'(\w[-\w]*)')` and `str_extract_all('stackoverflow.stack.com/read/this-is-a-very-nice-test',  regex('(\\w[-\\w]*)'))` or have `{1,}`

Comment: Technially, `myseries.str.extractall(r'([\w-]+)')` gives what you're looking for, although you can't avoid matching text that begins with the hyphen (to avoid that, use `r'(\w[\w-]+)'`)

Comment: thanks but i dont understand the discrepancy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(\w[-\w]+){2,}` regex represents a [*repeated capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html):

> The repeated capturing group will capture only the last iteration

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d48oT2/1), the substrings highlighted are the values you get in Pandas with [`.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) as this method expects a "*regular expression pattern with capturing groups*" and returns "*a `DataFrame` with one row for each match, and one column for each group*".

Opposite to Pandas `extractall`, the R [`stringr::str_extract_all`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) omits all captured substrings in its result and only "*extracts all matches and returns a list of character vectors*".

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ To make the pattern that works in both environments use `(\w[\w-]{3,})` since that is what your current pattern means: extract all words that start with a word char and then have 3 or more word or hyphen chars. If that is not what you wanted, and you need a fix, let know of the real requirements.

Comment: thanks!! something i dont get is the difference between captured substrings and matches

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Captured substrings are those that are matched with parenthesized pattern parts. Whole matches are the strings that are matched with the whole pattern. See [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is work as expected after change this part "{2,}" to "{1,}"

```
import re
s = 'stackoverflow.stack.com/read/this-is-a-very-nice-test'
out = re.findall(r'(\w[-\w]+){1,}', s)
print(out)
```

output:

```
['stackoverflow', 'stack', 'com', 'read', 'this-is-a-very-nice-test']
```

**EDIT:**
**Explanation from python prespective:**
repeating qualifier {m,n}, where m and n are decimal integers. This qualifier means there must be at least m repetitions, and at most n.

in your previous example "{2,}" you set m=2 and n to infinity which means a pattern should be repeated at least 2 times, 
but if you set m=1 as in "{1,}", it will accept a one time occurrence also it is equivalent to "+" i.e you can replace r'(\w[-\w]+){1,}' to (r'(\w[-\w]+)+' and still get the same result

Comment: thanks i know that I guess my point is why the same regex is returning different results